# how to show a Shopify's page text in a customized product tab

Tags: html, shopify

I have created custom tabs on my products page in Shopify.

How can I insert a code that basically says: **the content that goes here is = to the html content of this Shopify page?**

With custom tabs, I'm basically adding the text one-by-one in each product. However, if I ever changed something to my shipping policy, I would have to go back into each product one-by-one, to update the shipping tabs.

I would like to have the content on a shopify page, so when I edit that content, all the custom tabs on each product will copy the same content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So You want to create one area for all products if edit in that area then content will automatically updated for all products? If Yes then you have to do custom code in your product template.

- First of all You have to create a section in your product template using shopify schema and get this section value in product template.
- After that when you update content in your created area it will automatically for your all products.

It will be more easy for you if you having knowledge about Shopify Liquid code, Html etc. 
If you don't know about liquid code then you can hire person which know about liquid code.

Also Please let me know if you have any other query. I am happy to help you. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to go into your product section and in the schema code you need define a new area page (https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/settings#page) like this
{
"type":      "page",
"id":        "id",
"label":     "Text",
"info":      "Text"
}

After this in the TAB call this schema by its id and add the content.

Thanks